# ng-blur not setting true/false value in inline edit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, blur

I'm trying to set the view to readonly view(value that was there before modifying) in inline edit if clicked outside the input text box by firing `ng-blur`.But not working as expected.

Tried my code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/2IzdMl?p=preview)

```
<ul ng-init="showInput=false">
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
      <span ng-show="!showInput" ng-click="showInput=!showInput">{{todo.title}}</span>
      <span><input ng-show="showInput"  ng-model="todo.title" ng-blur="showInput=true"></span>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Don't you mean `ng-blur="showInput=false"` ?

Comment: @JorgeValle Updated the code as per your thoughts and working if I click inside the text block and come out of it.Is there any way on click of outside the <span> same functionality occurs by retaining the model.?

Comment: Also added `autofocus`  inside input text box for that behaviour but working only for the first click

Comment: @forgottofly You may know about this, but you can use [angular-xeditable](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried a plunker which as per my assumption of your problem check it out and if wrong please elobrate your problem

Added a blurfunction

```
    $scope.blurFunc = function(){
    $scope.showInput = true;
  }
```

[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/pJ2ikVko7wfols8P3GsK?p=preview)

Comment: @Vignesh.Please check comments in question.I'm trying to make inline edit and cancel edit by clicking outside input text box

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

Your code don't work correctly because when you click on span, span will hidde and input will show BUT don't receive the focus. For this reason when you click "outside" of input ngBlur never is trigger (input never receive focus). Check this clicking on span and click again on input. Input has received focus and when you click outside, ngBlur is triggered.

### Solution 1 (the best)

Use a directive with your span. This directive do focus on input when span is clicked. No more modifications on your code, but you need some knowledge whit directives.

### Solution 2 (poor, but you don't need a directive)

Show input with two boolean variables. One is true if when mouse is over span/input. The another one is true when you click, and false when ngBlur is triggered. Of course you need somethink like that `<input ng-show="mouseOver || showInput">`.